# One more statement regarding differentiation (one variable)

Tags: calculus

I will be glad to receive your thoughts about the following:

If a function $f$ is differentiable in a neighberhood of $x=a$ then it must also be differentiable at $x=a$ itself

.I guess it is true, but can't understand how to solve it

WIll someone please help me?

Thanks !

Comment: $y=|x|$ at $x=0$? Depends what you mean by "differentiable in a neighborhood".

Comment: I guess it is meant to be "from a out to some distance d from a, but not necessarily at x=a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|x|$ is differentiable in the neighbourhood of $0$ ($\pm 1$ depending on $x$), but what's the derivative at $0$?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is not true. Take $f(x)=|x|$. It is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$, but not at $x=0$.
2. The second, is also incorrect. The derivative of a differentiable function is not necessarily continuous. In fact, it can be almost everywhere discontinuous. The most famous example of a differentiable function with a discontinuous derivative is
   $$
   f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cll} x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{if} & x\ne 0,\\
   0 & \text{if} & x=0,
   \end{array}
   \right.
   $$
   which is everywhere differentiable, and its derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$.

However, question 2 possesses a reformulation which is valid:

*If $\,f : [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and the limit $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=A$ exists in $\mathbb R$, then $f$ possesses a right derivative at $x=a$ which is equal to $A$.*